# How to interpret maximum risetime on I²C communication timing specification

Tags: i2c, timing

I am using a [ICM-42605](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09/DS-000292-ICM-42605-v1.7.pdf) IMU in conjunction with a GNSS module, which has a blackbox firmware that realizes the communication with the IMU via I²C. I can see signs that the communication works fine, and can measure the lines directly.

I noticed that the rising edge of the I²C pulses looks a bit 'overdamped' and despite things working fine, decided to investigate a bit. Here is an image of a measured clock pulse:

[image]

The SDA and SCL pins are open drain and I have 3k3 resistors as pull-ups. The frequency can be up to 1MHz and seems to be 334kHz judging by the measurement. Also, the risetime of each pulse is about ~380ns, but the datasheet of the IMU specifies a maximum risetime of 120ns:

[image]

Here are my questions:

1. Is this maximum value fixed throughout frequencies? It seems to me that it would depend on the pulse width and, hence, why the circuit currently works as is.
2. Should I be looking to reduce the resistance values so as to reduce the risetime?

Comment: it looks fine, at this clock rate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I estimate that the rise time between 0.3×Vdd and 0.7xVdd is about 200ns.
That also approximates the capacitance to be about 60pF.

So it will violate timings of a 1 MHz FMPlus bus.

But you are not running in FM+ mode because the clock is below 400 kHz so this is in Fast Mode range. It allows for 300ns rise time, so this should be within i2C specification.

So I would say the rise time is OK. FMPlus chips are required to be downward compatible with slower bus modes.

The clock pulse spends more than the required 600ns above 0.7×Vdd which is also OK for Fast Mode bus.

1. I2C specs have different modes. The rise time specs are different e.g. within 0 to 100 kHz, 100 kHz to 400 kHz, and 400 kHz to 1MHz ranges.
2. You can but do not need to reduce the resistance to make the rise time faster if you work in Fast Mode. If you intend to make the clock faster and go into the Fast Mode Plus range and near 1 MHz, then you must reduce the resistance to meet the rise time requirement.

While the requirement is a requirement, generally, you also need to be reasonable. You don't need to go from 300ns to 120ns rise time just because you switched from 399 kHz to 401 kHz clock, in practice it is enough that you meet the pulse to be at least 500ns while meeting Vih of all chips. But, it is good to be strictly within specfications if you need to prove someone that the bus meets and is well within official specifications.

Answer (score 2):

These values are just copied from the [I²C specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) for Fast-mode Plus devices. But those requirements apply only when your devices actually use Fast-mode Plus speeds.

The I²C specification says about Fast-mode Plus:

> The drivers in Fast-mode Plus parts are strong enough to satisfy the Fast-mode Plus timing specification with the same 400 pF load as Standard-mode parts. To be backward compatible with Standard-mode, they are also tolerant of the 1 μs rise time of Standard-mode parts.

The allowed rise times are 1 µs for Standard-mode (up to 100 kHz), or 300 ns for Fast-mode (up to 400 kHz). Also note that the rise time is measured from 30 % to 70 % of V<sub>DD</sub>, so your waveform is OK.

The I²C specification limits the pull-up current to 3 mA. So you would be allowed to use stronger resistors, but that is not necessary in your case.

Comment: Slight misconception. I2C specs do not limit the current to 3mA. It is actually the other way around, chips must be able to sink at least 3mA while guaranteeing 0.4V level, and to use 400 kHz with full 400pF capacitance, parts must be capable of sinking 6mA guaranteeing 0.6V, and 20mA at 0.4V for FMPlus.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that the real rise time is smaller. This may be due to the fact that the pull-up resistor, together with the probe capacitance, creates a low-pass filter and therefore the measurements are incorrect. It is best to use a Z0 probe for such measurements - a coaxial cable that is terminated at the input to the oscilloscope and has a resistor at the output, e.g. 953 Ohms, which creates a 1:20 probe.

https://hackaday.io/project/162998-the-rise-and-fall-of-pulses/log/162893-my-old-favorite-z0-probe

Comment: The capacitance on the bus is approximately 60pF in total, the probe could add 10 to 20 pF so the rise time measured will be better than pictured. In this case, it is an extremely poor idea to suggest a Z0 probe. You cannot measure an I2C bus which is an open-drain bus with 3.3k pull-ups, by loading it with a homemade Z0 probe which pulls the bus down with 1kohm resistance.

Comment: That is fact that voltage levels will be disrupt but the rise time will be measured more acuratelly. What's more it is also possible to use 10k or even 100k resistor to get working I2C and well measured rise time.